# Beautifullsoup: How to grab the contents of an <a> tag thats within a <h1>?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to extract the name from a twitter profile, the only problem I'm having is that beautifulsoup grabs the entire element. I have tried the `{"class":}` to specify the element but whenever I do this it results in getting

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' error.

My code:

```
url = "https://twitter.com/barackobama"
html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

name = soup.find('h1').text
print(name)
```

Comment: Note that scraping the Twitter website is against the Twitter Terms of Service, and may result in your IP address being blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the text from child link of header instead of complete header text, try

```
url = "https://twitter.com/barackobama"
html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

name = soup.find('h1').a.text
print(name)
# 'Barack Obama'
```

Comment: This would not fix the error described in the question, even if OP seems to have thought it worked. `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` implies that `soup.find('h1')` returned `None`, in which case `.a` would **also** not work.